# "Dearly-missed hometown" or "dearly missed hometown?"

Tags: adjectives, hyphens

The reason of my confusion is that I get both on [Google](https://www.google.com.tw/search?q=%22dearly-missed%20hometown%22&biw=1265&bih=807&ei=yvUxVeuoMNTr8AX9uYDYDw&start=10&sa=N):

> Back in Lakewood, our **dearly missed hometown**. We used to buy our
>   birthday cakes from a fabulous little neighborhood shop called Cakes
>   by ...
>
> But if you live in my **dearly-missed hometown** of Philly,
>   well, you probably go about things a little bit differently. Take one
>   Fatai King, a man with ...

Which is the right version, and why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hyphen is not needed between an adverb and the adjective it modifies. The meaning is perfectly clear without a hyphen.

I wouldn't say it's *wrong* to put one in, but my advice is to save your hyphens for when you *really need them* for clarity.